# Show that $p(x) = a_nx^n+a...+a_1x+a_0$ either has a root or attains minimum value in R.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Show that if $p(x) = a_nx^n +\dots+ a_1x + a_0$ and $a_n > 0$, then either $p(x) = 0$ has a solution, or else $p(x)$ has attains minimum value on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm sorry I don't know how to even start the problem. I know that if it is an odd degree polynomial then it has roots.

Thank you. The second part confuses me the most. This is from an undergrad Real Analysis homework.

Comment: You have covered the case when $n$ is odd,  If $n$ is even $\lim_\limits{n\to -\infty} = \infty$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} = \infty$ and if $p(x)$ has no roots, for all $x, p(x) > 0.$  It is bounded below, which means that it must have a greatest lower bound... which is your minimum.

Comment: Have you investigated its stationary points?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then there is $R$ such that for $|x|>R$ we have that $p(x)>p(0)$. Inside the interval $[-R,R]$ the function attains its minimum $M$, since $p$ is continuous and $[-R,R]$ is a compact interval. This minimum satisfies $M\leq p(0)$. Therefore, $M$ is the global minimum of $p$ and it is attained, at least, in $[-R,R]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ has no roots, consider $f(x) = |\frac{1}{p(x)}|$. This is well-defined and continuous, and for some $N$, we have that $|x| > N$ implies $f(x) < 1$. Now $f$ assumes a max on the compact $[-N,N]$....

Answer (score 1):

If your polynomial is of an odd degree, then:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}a_n\cdot x^n=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}p(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}a_n\cdot x^n=+\infty$$
So there is a root, or else there is a $x$ where $p(x)=0$.

If your polynomial is of an even degree, then you are not sure if it has a root. But it's first derivative $p'(x)$ is a polynomial of an odd degree($p'(x)=a_n n x^{n-1}+...+a_1$). As I showed before this polynomial has a root, which means there is an $x$ for which $p'(x)=0$, which in turn means that there are some $x$ where $p(x)$ has it's local minimum or local maximum value. Since $a_n>0$ and $p(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ when $x\to-\infty$ or $+\infty$ then at at least one $x$ of the above equation the polynomial has a global minimum value.

So we proved that for any polynomial either it has a root or it has a minimum value.

Comment: You proved existence of local minima. This is different from having a minimum. The function $\log([x]^2+1/2)$ tends to $+\infty$ when $|x|\to+\infty$, has many local minima but no minimum and no zero.

Comment: Every polynomial of an even degree with $a_n>0$ tends to infinity when x tens to infinity. So this local minimum is at the same time the total minimum.

Comment: That argument is not correct. To begin with, the local minima need not be unique and the values of $p$ at those points need not be the same. So, some of them are not going to be global minimum. Think about it longer.

Comment: Yes but there is at least one which is a global minimum.

Comment: You need to prove that.

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense, my only concern is though (and pardon me for my ineptitude) is how I can relate the derivative back to the original function? We just recently started learning about derivatives.

Comment: Ok. I am going to edit it. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: @MehakWahla Careful! This argument is incomplete, and to complete it, you practically need to give an argument that in itself could be the direct proof of your problem.

Comment: "then at at least one x of the above equation the polynomial has a global minimum value.". Ask and answer yourself this question: Why is that claim true? As the example in my first comment shows, that requires a proof, since it is not always true for arbitrary functions.

Comment: @MehakWahla Sorry, but I didn't understand very well your question! Could you please rephrase that again? And please tell me if my answer helped you at all giving me a feedback!

Comment: @pompelle I am sorry if I didn't understood sth well, but I found the limits of the polynomial at -infinity and +infinity.

Comment: It is simple, you made a claim, which requires proof. You need to prove it. But let me warn you of something. The vanishing of the derivative is not going to get you far. The thing is that one first need to prove existence of the global minimum. Once you know that it exists then Fermat's theorem tells you that the derivative vanishes there. The existence is the original question anyway. The existence of the minimum is going to follow, giving a proof, from the limits and the continuity of $p$. You will see that looking at the derivative was not relevant.

Comment: @pompelle Oh, I understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that polynomials are continuous on $\Bbb R$; note that $p(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$; if $p(x)\lt 0$ for some $x=a$, apply IVT to $p$ on $[a,\infty)$; if $p(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$, recall that $\Bbb R$ has the glb property.

Comment: Doesn't the IVT apply only to a closed interval?

Comment: @MehakWahla: If you want to be pedant, $p(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ is equivalent to saying that given $M\gt 0$ there exists $m\in\Bbb R$ such that for all $x\gt m$, we have $p(x)\geq M\gt 0$; you can apply IVT to $p(x)$ on $[a,m]$

Answer (score 0):

We recall the well-known fact that polynomials are continuous; thus:

If such a polynomial $p(x)$,

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n a_i x^i, \tag 1$

with $a_n > 0$, has no roots, then $n = \deg p(x)$ is even; for if $\deg p(x)$ were odd, then since $a_n > 0$, and the highest degree term $a_n x^n$ dominates for sufficiently large $\vert x \vert$, that is,

$x \to -\infty \Longrightarrow p(x) \to -\infty, \tag 2$

$x \to \infty \Longrightarrow p(x) \to \infty; \tag 3$

it is but a short step, *via* the intermediate value theorem, to see that $p(x)$ has a zero in $\Bbb R$.  So if $p(x)$ has no root, then $\deg p(x)$ is even.  But then we have, again since $a_n > 0$, that

$\vert x \vert \to \infty \Longrightarrow p(x) \to \infty; \tag 4$

this means that, given any $B > 0$, there exists $L>0$ such that

$\vert x \vert > L \Longrightarrow p(x) > B; \tag 5$

we also observe that

$p(0) = a_0 > 0; \tag 6$

since $p(x)$ never $0$, it cannot change sign; thus (6) follows from (4)-(5).  If we now choose $B > a_0$, and $L$ accordingly large, we affirm that the continuous function $p(x)$ attains its minimum value $p_{min} \le a_0$ at some $x_0 \in [-L, L]$.

And *that* is indeed *that*, is it not?